# Get IP address of a kamailio user

Tags: kamailio

I have installed a sip kamailio proxy.

I'd like to find the IP address associated with my kamailio (registered) sip users but I can't find where it is stored and how to retreive it.

My guess is to use db_query from SQLOps module but I can't find the right table in my mysql database.

Does someone knows how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found that the [location table](http://kamailio.org/docs/db-tables/kamailio-db-4.2.x.html#gen-db-location) has a "received" column that contains the IP address of a registered user (a regexp is necessary though).